# I wish to print out the first two characters from $TEXT

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

I want my program to print out the text that I typed followed by the first two characters of that text. Is there any way to do this?

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Get text from user repeatedly
#
echo "Type away..."
while read TEXT
do
    echo You typed $TEXT
    if [ "$TEXT" = "quit" ] || [ "$TEXT" = "q" ] || [ "$TEXT" = "Q" ] || [ "$TEXT" = "QUIT" ]; then
        echo So I quit!
        exit 0
    fi
done

echo "HELP!"
```

Comment: ALthough I don't understand the question entirely. If you type `foobar` what would you want to see? `fo` or `ar` or `foobarar`?

Answer (score 9):

You can get the first characters using notation like `${var:0:N}` where *var* is the variable name and *N* is number of characters you want. So, for your question, `${TEXT:0:2}` should give you the first two characters in `TEXT`. Example:

```
TEXT="Some text"
echo "\$TEXT: '$TEXT', first 2 chars: '${TEXT:0:2}'"
```

Output:

```
$TEXT: 'Some text', first 2 chars: 'So'
```

[The Linux Documentation Project](https://www.tldp.org/) has a chapter called ["Manipulating Strings"](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html). The "substring extraction" section has more details about this notation.

Answer (score 4):

Just to provide you a general idea. In your case you can use `case`... `esac` construction. An example shown here

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

call_for_help()
{
  echo "Please help!" >&2
}

if (($# < 1)); then
  call_for_help
fi

while read -rp "Type away: " TEXT; 
do
  echo "${TEXT:0:2}"
  case "$TEXT" in
   [qQ] | [Qq]uit)
      echo "You quited"
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: (1) I applaud the use of `case`…`esac` and the `[Ww][Oo][Rr][Dd]` notation, but you should probably state that your code is not functionally equivalent to the OP's.  The OP's script will recognize only `q`, `Q`, `quit` and `QUIT`; yours will recognize those *and also* `Quit`, `qUIT`, `quIt`, and 11 other variants.  (2) The whole point of saying `while read …` … `do` instead of `while true` ... `do read …` is to have the loop end when the `read` fails, as happens when it reads an EOF (end of a file, or Ctrl+D on a terminal). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  By injecting the `echo` statements between the `read` and the `do`, you create a loop that cannot be terminated by Ctrl+D (and will spin forever if given input from a file).  (3) So it's adding insult to injury that your code ***doesn't quit*** when the user tells it to!  (4) Why are you displaying the last two characters of the input?  (5) Why are you treating the input as an array?  (6) What's this about `$OPTARG`?

Comment: @G-Man I think your comments are very valid indeed. The last line `$OPTARG` will of course be valid only when `getopts` is used. Also I put there 2 options (array var and the other one) since the question wasn't clear what OP wanted. Furthermore,  it is indeed pointless to have the variable there in between. I'm going to make some changes so others aren't confused!  Thanks for the comments